# How to mkdir in Firefox-Addon-sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I create a new directory/folder programatically? I'm downloading mp3s and saving them but I want to seperate them by genre (newDirectoryName). Here's my code so far..

```
function DownloadFile(sLocalFileName, newDirectoryName, sRemoteFileName)
{


    var saveToDirectory = 'C:\\Users\\louis\\downloads\\'+newDirectoryName+'\\';

    console.log("downloading : "+saveToDirectory);

    var chrome = require("chrome");

    var oIOService = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(chrome.Ci.nsIIOService)

    var oLocalFile = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(chrome.Ci.nsILocalFile);
    oLocalFile.initWithPath(saveToDirectory + sLocalFileName);

    var oDownloadObserver = {onDownloadComplete: function(nsIDownloader, nsresult, oFile) {console.log('download complete...')}};

    var oDownloader = chrome.Cc["@mozilla.org/network/downloader;1"].createInstance();
    oDownloader.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIDownloader);
    oDownloader.init(oDownloadObserver, oLocalFile);

    var oHttpChannel = oIOService.newChannel(sRemoteFileName, "", null);
    oHttpChannel.QueryInterface(chrome.Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    oHttpChannel.asyncOpen(oDownloader, oLocalFile);    


    console.log("should be downloading!!!!");

}
DownloadFile('filename.mp3','genre','http://domain.com/file.mp3');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the [OS.File module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread) and use `makeDir`

Answer (score 1):

Also, the SDK provides [file utilites](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html#mkpath%28path%29), like mkpath (mkdir -p)

In FF25 I believe (currently in Nightly), the `io/fs` module will become available, which has parity with [node's fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)